# Sending mail using java : file is not getting attached from local system

Tags: java, email, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I am developing a web application using Oracle ADF and jdeveloper11.1.2.4. In that I have a form to send a mail with required input fields. Example toAddress, ccAddress and attachemnt Location(input text field). I am sending mails using java mail api. I got this information from the post
[Mail using java](http://www.journaldev.com/2532/java-program-to-send-email-using-smtp-gmail-tls-ssl-attachment-image-example)

My problems is with attachment file. I am able to send an email successfully with attachment if I gave a location of the file that is on server(on which my application has deployed).

Beacause my application is web application user can access through internet. If am trying to add a location of the file that is in local system(Other than server) then file is not getting attached and mail is not getting send.

I am unable to attach a file from other than server.

Please help me. How do I achieve this. User should be able to attache a file from his/her system(local system).

Comment: You'll have to upload the file to the server that's sending the email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First upload your file to server directory 
see- http://www.awasthiashish.com/2014/08/uploading-and-downloading-files-from.html

Then provide a path when sending mail 
see-http://www.awasthiashish.com/2013/04/gmail-integration-with-oracle-adf-using.html

Answer (score 1):

First you will have to upload the file to the server and then attach that file in your email as JavaMail will need an absolute path on your current server.

PS: If you are sending emails using java I would highly recommend looking at Apache Commons email library https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email/userguide.html

It will make your life a lot easier.